# MiPS32bits What is the highest and lowest value?

Tags: assembly, mips32

Which major and minor address that the beq instruction can achieve in 32-bit mips. With the value 0x000C0000 stored.

Comment: did you look at the instruction set documentation?  the answer is there.

Answer (score 0):

The beq is an I format instruction. So the immediate value is 16 bits, these 16bits is being filled by the **steps you want to skip** so you can go (2^16)-1 steps down and (2^16) step up ('cuz it will be negative). And wherever was the label you are going to branch to, the assembler always has the solution xD. I mean the assembler converts the instruction into some instructions that achieve the label if it wasn't in the range of it. The point is **it doesn't take address** as you think. And what is the value "0x000C0000 ", I mean what does it have to do?